# A more idiomatic way to write sanctuary pipe

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, sanctuary

I wrote a code snippet that extracts the `source` object keys (which are supposed to be unknown so I've added a non-existing key `baz` to be extracted.
Every element in the array that I extract - I want to add the key from which It was extracted and then flatten the result to get a single array.

I've encountered two major issues while writing the code:

1. When trying to use `S.insert`, It always returned an error because the object values (numbers `{r:**<<number>>**}`) were of different type than the string i've tried to add to the key `Section` (`{'Section': **'foo'**}` for example). I ended up mutating the object just for the sake of conveying my intention.
2. I didn't manage to write a proper map function that would abstract over the `Maybe` and let me access the variables inside. So I had to use `S.maybeToNullable` and then re-wrap the value into `Maybe`.
3. Is there a better way of expressing any logic written below with `sanctuary`?

The code snippet:

```
const S = require('sanctuary');
const source = {
  foo: [{ r: 1 }, { r: 2 }, { r: 3 }],
  bar: [{ r: 4 }, { r: 5 }, { r: 6 }],
}

const result =
  S.pipe([
    S.map(
      prop => {
        const nullable = S.maybeToNullable(S.value(prop)(source))
        return nullable ? S.Just(nullable.map(val => {val['Section'] = prop; return val})) : S.Nothing
      }
    ),
    S.justs,
    S.reduce(xs => x => [...xs, ...x])([])
  ])(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
const S = require ('sanctuary');

//    source :: StrMap (Array { r :: Integer })
const source = {
  foo: [{r: 1}, {r: 2}, {r: 3}],
  bar: [{r: 4}, {r: 5}, {r: 6}],
  quux: [{r: 7}, {r: 8}],
};

//    result :: Array { r :: Integer, Section :: String }
const result =
S.filter (S.compose (S.flip (S.elem) (['foo', 'bar', 'baz']))
                    (S.prop ('Section')))
         (S.chain (S.pair (s => S.map (S.unchecked.insert ('Section') (s))))
                  (S.pairs (source)));
```

There are several things to note:

- [`S.pipe`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#pipe) does not feel natural to me in this case as there are two inputs (`source` and `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`). Using `S.pipe` would necessitate hard-coding one of these inputs in the pipeline.
- [`S.insert`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#insert) cannot be used for updating records, but `S.unchecked.insert` can be used for this purpose. I appreciate being able to suppress type checking when an expression I know to be sound is considered unsound by the type checker.
- It's not clear to me from your question whether output order is important. Your solution respects the order of the array of section names; mine does not. Let me know whether output order is important.

Comment: Sorry, It looks much more complicated and unreadable. I come from other languages with FP capabilities and I know for sure that this isn't what I'm looking for. Can you address the issues `1` and `2` I've mentioned? I'd be happy to first solve those problems.

Comment: `S.value (prop) (source)` gives a `Maybe (Array { r :: Integer })`. To operate on the `{ r :: Integer }` you will need to map *twice*. Try replacing your lambda with `prop => S.map (S.map (S.unchecked.insert ('Section') (prop))) (S.value (prop) (source))`.